# Responsibility of a controller in AngularJS - More than two views?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I come from the Rails world, where a controller is responsible to do business logic but a single controller can render several views, depending on the action that is supposed to do.

However, and after doing some research on AngularJS, I have the feeling that a controller will just have one responsability (associated with a single view). So, for example, if we have an application that lists restaurants, we would have the following:

```
@restauranteur.config(['$routeProvider', ($routeProvider) ->
  $routeProvider.
    when('/restaurants', {
      templateUrl: '../templates/restaurants/index.html',
      controller: 'RestaurantIndexCtrl'
    }).
    when('/restaurants/:id', {
      templateUrl: '../templates/restaurants/show.html',
      controller: 'RestaurantShowCtrl'
    }).
    otherwise({
      templateUrl: '../templates/home.html',
      controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    })
])
```

One controller would be used for the 'index' and another for the 'show'.  Is this the correct approach/suggested approach in Angular?

Comment: @lokers has a great answer, but I'll add a note that "view" might not be tied one-to-one with a url, even though that is often the case. I tend to think of it as one controller per template object or scope not otherwise controller by a directive. You could have several `ng-controller` directives inside a view, creating child/sibling scopes under the view. This is good question, and a fairly advanced one in the Angular world considering the role directives and controllers play in best practices for Angular apps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can read in official documentation, in general, a Controller shouldn't try to do too much. It should contain only the business logic needed for a single view.

The most common way to keep Controllers slim is by encapsulating work that doesn't belong to controllers into services and then using these services in Controllers via dependency injection.

In Angular, a Controller is a JavaScript constructor function that is used to augment the Angular Scope.

When a Controller is attached to the DOM via the ng-controller directive, Angular will instantiate a new Controller object, using the specified Controller's constructor function. A new child scope will be available as an injectable parameter to the Controller's constructor function as $scope.

**Use controllers to:**

- Set up the initial state of the $scope object.
- Add behavior to the $scope object.

**Do not use controllers to:**

- Manipulate DOM — Controllers should contain only business logic. Putting any presentation logic into Controllers significantly affects its testability. Angular has databinding for most cases and directives to encapsulate manual DOM manipulation.
- Format input — Use angular form controls instead.
- Filter output — Use angular filters instead.
- Share code or state across controllers — Use angular services instead.
- Manage the life-cycle of other components (for example, to create service instances).

To answer shortly your question - yes, this is correct approach